# Psexec worked once and now access denied

Tags: command-prompt, remote-access, access-denied, psexec

I ran a batch file on a remote machine using the command in PsExec v2.11

```
[path]\psexec.exe \\[myserver] "D:\Automation\BatchFiles\Test.bat"
```

The first time it worked perfectly.  After that, running it causes an "Access Denied" error.

What would cause this and how can I fix it?

Edit:  After waiting 30 minutes or so I was able to run it once again, and now access denied.

Upon further inspection, when I rdc to the server and try to save changes to the batch file after successfully using psexec, it says it's being used by another process.

Another Edit: Manually logging out and back into the rdc 'fixes' the problem.  Can both PSexec and save the file.

Answer (score 1):

In my situtaion, using "-r" parameter with random service name solved the problem. This parameter (-r) is defined as:

> Specifies the name of the remote service to create or interact with.

at microsoft technet (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)
Change the service name everytime, this will probably help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because myserver is slow to tidy up after the first run, and c:\windows\psexec.exe is being held by open by the System PID, so it cannot be clobered by the subsequent run od psexec.
I am using an Oracle agentDeployPsExec.bat script to deploy an EM agent to 10 "identical" servers.  It works on some but not others.
The myserver servers take 1-4 minutes to remove c:\windows\psexec.exe, and are not busy and have symantec turned off.
The servers that do work have a persistent service, PSEXESVC, present, that runs c:\windows\psexesvc.exe (owner by BUILTIN\Administrators vs "...").  This service is created by a successful psexec run, then removed on exit by the dodgey servers.